# Xubuntu installation

Tags: system-installation

Here is my hardware:    Atom D2550 1.86GHzx4, 2.0TB HD, 4.0 RAM
Need help to install Xubuntu. Any one can give me step by step instruction.
Previous version is 12.04 LTS with Graphic interface.

Comment: Why do you need help? What do you need help with? What's the problem?

Comment: Xubuntu uses the same `ubiquity` installer as Ubuntu itself uses, so it's no different.  The difference is post-install; you're using the Xubuntu/XFCE interface instead of the Ubuntu/GNOME desktop.  Installation however is identical.